# Select2 Drop Down To Display Pre Fetched Data

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-4, jquery-plugins, jquery-select2

I have the following code:

```
<hr class="col-sm-10"/>
<form class="col-sm-10 form-horizontal">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="test" class="control-label col-sm-2">Name</label>
        <div class="col-sm-10">
            <select class="col-sm-10 form-control" id="tenantList">

            </select>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>

<script>
    var tenants = [];
        $.ajax({
                url: 'api/Tenant'
            })
            .done(function (data) {
                tenants = data;
            })
            .fail(function () {
                console.log("Problem :(");
            });

    $('#tenantList').select2({
        placeholder: "Select a tenant",
        allowClear: true,
        data: tenants
    });
</script>
```

*tenants* variable is not being set to the returned JSON array. The data is coming from Server successfully, still the variable is empty. What am I doing wrong? What be the right way to do it in Select2 ?

Comment: you try do first answer?

Comment: @ChristianCarrillo thanks for the reply. Unfortunately I need to read up more about Select2. My response does not is and text property. Reading up how to handle such situation

Answer (score 0):

Move select2 instruction inside done ajax

```
<hr class="col-sm-10"/>
<form class="col-sm-10 form-horizontal">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="test" class="control-label col-sm-2">Name</label>
        <div class="col-sm-10">
            <select class="col-sm-10 form-control" id="tenantList">

            </select>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>

<script>
    var tenants = [];
        $.ajax({
                url: 'api/Tenant'
            })
            .done(function (data) {
                tenants = data;
                $('#tenantList').select2({
                  placeholder: "Select a tenant",
                  allowClear: true,
                  data: tenants
                });
            })
            .fail(function () {
                console.log("Problem :(");
            });


</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

After you get the data, you need to assign your returned data from ajax to 'data' for select2:

```
function callajax() {
  $.ajax({
      url: 'api/Tenant'
    })
    .done(function(data) {
      $('#tenantList').select2({
        placeholder: "Select a tenant",
        width: "200px",
        allowClear: true,
        data: data
      });
    })
    .fail(function() {
      console.log("Problem :(");
    });
}

callajax();
```

hope it helps

https://jsfiddle.net/dalinhuang/3bmf11x7/